# set window title from listboxitem name

Tags: c#, wpf, window, set, title

This is my first time coding in C# and building applications in VS2010.

My task is to build a application, that has two windows. First with `ListBox` with several items. The second one opens on `MouseDoubleClick` on any item. At that point, second window opens and the **title of it should be the same as ListBoxItem Name**.

I have searched for a way to do this. But had no luck what so ever.

At this point I have this in code:

...

```
namespace WpfApplication20
{

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var newWindow = new Window1();
            newWindow.Show();
        }

        private void seznamSporocil_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            var newWindow = new Window1();
            newWindow.Show();
        } 
    }
}
```

At the end this should be an Email application, like Outlook or similar.

Thank you for all the help!

Comment: You have searched for a way to do this and missed the [Title](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.title.aspx) property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst Freelancers answer is somewhat right, his solution assumes that the event was and will always be triggered by that one specific ListBox. You should really use the sender parameter to get a reference to the listbox that was triggering the event though, like so:

```
    private void seznamSporocil_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var listBox = sender as ListBox;
        var item = listBox.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem;

        var newWindow = new Window1();
        newWindow.Title = item.Content.ToString();
        newWindow.Show();
    }
```

Some error-checking would not hurt either, i.e. verify wheather the sender object really is a ListBox-Type, etc.

Comment: Unless items are explicitly added as instances of `ListBoxItem` the expression `listBox.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem` will always return `null`. If you add for example `string` items to a ListBox, `SelectedItem` returns the selected items as `string`.

Comment: @Clemens: Thats right - but then verifying casts _is_ error checking. As I mentioned one needs to verify whether the sender is of the type ListBox as well - which is not done in the small code snippet as it simply aint really part of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try with following:

```
var newWindow = new Window1();
newWindow.Title = listBox.SelectedItem.toString();
newWindow.Show();
```

**Link:**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.window.title.aspx

Hope its helpful.

Comment: sorry, its WPF, it has to be title.